# Почему не копируется строка?

Tags: c++

```
strcpy(ResText, matrix[ind_x1][0]);
```

ругается хотя и тот и другой массив char

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(144): E2034 Cannot convert 'int' to 'const char *'
```

А кроме этого можно же как-то дописывать строки пробовал += не работает

Comment: Покажите объявления `ResText` и `matrix`

Comment: #define SIZE 250
#define SIZE_2 5
char matrix[SIZE_2][SIZE_2];
char ResText[SIZE] = {0};

Answer (score 1):

Сложно сказать, что такое `matrix`, но, возможно, он не содержит двойной массив указателей на символы.

> А кроме этого можно же как-то дописывать строки пробовал += не работает

Создайте `std::string` или `std::wstring` из массива символов и потом заработает `+=`.

Строки в С (а `char*` - это именно С-строка) представляют собой указатели на начало строки, при этом конец строки определяется терминирующим символов `\0`. Для указателей += или + имеет совсем другую семантику: семантику адресной арифметики, а не манипуляцию с содержимым строки.

Другими словами: `cstr + 1` переместит указатель строки к следующему символу, а `str1 + str2` просто сложит два указателя, в результате чего новый указатель будет указывать на мусор.

Вообще, я бы рекомендовал взять С++-е контейнеры и строки. Если нужен массив строк, то стоит воспользоваться `std::vector<std::string>`, и не морочить голову с адресной арифметикой и С-строками.

Comment: matrix это просто массив который заполнен символами [5][5]
В какой заголовочный файл входит std::string?
Просто я использую уже using namespace std

Comment: Если matrix - это двумерный массив, то для получения i-й строки нужно использовать matrix[i], вторая индексация даст доступ к символом i-й строки.

`include <string>` для включения класса `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

Надо же, еще кто-то пользуется билдером.
Судя по всему, `matrix[ind_x1][0]` у вас содержит один символ (char).
Если вам нужно скопировать только 1 символ, тогда так:

```
ResText[0] = matrix[ind_x1][0];
ResText[1]  = 0;
```

Если вы хотите скопировать всю строку (столбец), тогда так:

```
strcpy(ResText, matrix[ind_x1]);
```

Чтобы дописывать строки, используйте функцию [strcat](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcat/), ну а лучше, конечно, использовать std::string.

Comment: ну там получается мне нужно взять один символ из массива matrix[5][5] и дописать его в ResText[250]
matrix уже забит символами а вот ResText пустой

Comment: strcat выдает туже ошибку